# Is it safe to unsafeThaw an indexed unboxed vector?

Tags: arrays, haskell, mutability, referential-transparency, st-monad

[I just posted this code:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40578268/745903)

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as VU
import qualified Data.Vector.Algorithms.Intro as VAlgo

argSort :: (Ord a, VU.Unbox a) => VU.Vector a -> VU.Vector Int
argSort xs = VU.map fst $ VU.create $ do
    xsi <- VU.unsafeThaw $ VU.indexed xs
    VAlgo.sortBy (comparing snd) xsi
    return xsi
```

My reasoning was that [`unsafeThaw`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.11.0.0/docs/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html#v:unsafeThaw) is safe to use here because I only thaw the [`indexed`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.11.0.0/docs/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html#v:indexed) version of `xs`. However, then it occured to me that unboxed vectors of tuples – like these index-value pairs here – are really stored as *two* unboxed vectors, one for the indices and one for the values. Hence it seems plausible that `indexed` would not actually generate a new value vector at all, but just couple it with an index vector. In this case, `ST`-modifying `xsi` could possibly mess up `xs`.

Upon testing, this does not seem to happen though. *Can I rely on this, or should I better use [`thaw`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.11.0.0/docs/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html#v:thaw)?*

Comment: Seems like an implementation accident to me. I wouldn't rely on it.

Comment: This seems worthy of discussion for vector devs. At least "The immutable vector may not be used after this operation" does not seem to be well-defined or sufficient documentation, and I could easily see myself accidentally using an unsafeThaw in this situation without thinking about it.

Comment: A quick glance at [the source code](https://github.com/haskell/vector/blob/master/Data/Vector/Unboxed.hs#L812-L814) reveals that `indexed` is just an alias for [the overloaded version of the same](https://github.com/haskell/vector/blob/master/Data/Vector/Generic.hs#L1000-L1002), which works by converting the input vector to and from a stream. So `indexed`, as implemented, will always return a new vector, rather than a view over the old one. I guess the `Vector` devs decided fusion was more important than sharing in this case. I wouldn't necessarily want to rely on this behaviour though.